# How to force order of array in minizinc

Tags: minizinc

Lets say I have array,and number of rows as follows and I want to decide in which order they come.

```
set of int: people = 1..10;
int row= 3 
include "alldifferent.mzn";
constraint alldifferent(position);
array[people] of var people: position;
```

I have to people in the front row to come before people in behind rows; regardless of a column. Two people are in the same row if person1 mod row=person2 mod row, e.g. persons 2,5,8 are in the same row. I want to force this order in decision variable positions.

I found a naive way of doing so involving forall and exists which I believe is not efficient:

```
constraint forall(person in position where person>row)(exists(smallerpos in 1..person-1)(smallerpos div row = person div row));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, but the model is quite faster if you add `all_different(position)`, e.g.

```
include "globals.mzn"; % adding this

set of int: people = 1..10;
int row= 3 
array[people] of var people: position; 

constraint
   forall(pos1,pos2 in people where pos1 < pos2   /\ (position[pos1] mod row)=(position[pos2] mod row))
  (
      position[pos1] < position[pos2]
  )
  /\ all_different(position) % adding this
;
```

Without `all_different` it takes 0.9s to get all 4200 solutions, with `all_different` it takes 0.25s.

Note: I first thought of the following solution, but since it don't give the same number of solution it's probably not correct. It only give 1201 solutions, but it's faster: 0.05s. As mentioned above, I probably don't understand your problem correctly.

```
constraint
   forall(r in 0..row-1) (
       increasing([position[p] | p in people where p mod row == r])
    )
    /\ all_different(position)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but is less efficient.

```
constraint forall(pos1,pos2 in people where pos1 < pos2   /\ (position[pos1] mod rows)=(position[pos2] mod rows))(
  position[pos1] < position[pos2] );
```

Another proposition is, this one is not any more efficeint either

```
constraint forall(pos1,pos2 in people where (position[pos1] mod rows)=(position[pos2] mod rows))(
 pos1 < pos2 <-> position[pos1] < position[pos2] );
```